# Convert Multi dimensional array to Single array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Request your help on how to convert the below array as a single array, I tried all these methods:

```
array_column($testarray, "Name") ,
array_merge($array, , $testarray),
array_map('current', $$testarray[0])
```

but nothing seem to be working. Basically I need to passes the array value as a string using implode("','", Name) so that the array value would be like below

```
T : 'Name1','Name2'
D : 'Name11','Name21'
P : 'Name111','Name211'
```

**Original Array**

```
Array
(
    [T] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Name1
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Name2
                )
        )

    [D] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Name11
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Name21
                )
        )

    [P] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Name111
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Name211
                )
        )
)
```

**Expected Array**

```
T:
  Name: Name1
        Name2
D:
  Name: Name11
        Name21
P:
  Name: Name111
        Name211
```

From,
Vino

Comment: This question has an unclear desired result which has lead to different contributors providing different result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
function array_flatten($array) { 
  if (!is_array($array)) { 
    return FALSE; 
  } 
  $result = array(); 
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
    if (is_array($value)) { 
      $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value)); 
    } 
    else { 
      $result[$key] = $value; 
    } 
  } 
  return $result; 
}
```

Comment: This answer is either provably incorrect or it is missing the implementation aspect to demonstrate jow to make it work. https://3v4l.org/eTj7I  This answer is also missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten your array using `array_map` and `array_column`:

```
$newarr = array_map(function ($v) { return array_column($v, 'Name'); }, $array);
print_r($newarr);
```

This gives:

```
Array
(
    [T] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name1
            [1] => Name2
        )
    [D] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name11
            [1] => Name21
        )
    [P] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name111
            [1] => Name211
        )
)
```

You can then output the key with each array imploded for your string result:

```
foreach ($newarr as $key => $arr) {
    echo "$key: " . implode(',', $arr) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
T: Name1,Name2
D: Name11,Name21
P: Name111,Name211
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/QZB2F)

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = [
'T' => [['Name' => 'Name1'], ['Name' => 'Name2']],
'D' => [['Name' => 'Name11'], ['Name' => 'Name11']],
'P' => [['Name' => 'Name111'], ['Name' => 'Name211']]
];

array_walk($arr,function(&$v, $k){
    $v = ['Name' => array_column($v, 'Name')];
});

print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [T] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Name1
                    [1] => Name2
                )

        )

    [D] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Name11
                    [1] => Name11
                )

        )

    [P] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Name111
                    [1] => Name211
                )

        )

)
```